# Creating formula from matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a dataframe like so in R

**Expected Input:**

```
arc.set <- matrix(c("Q", "A",
                    "G", "A",
                    "G", "D",
                    "D", "A"),
                  byrow = TRUE, ncol = 2,
                  dimnames = list(NULL, c("from", "to")))
```

```
from to
Q    A
G    A
G    D
D    A
```

I want to make a formula like so based on the matrix above. Basically there are two unique letters in the "to" column and i want to get every unique letter from the "from" column that relates to the unique letters in the "to" column in the following format:

```
to_col ~ from_col_1 + ... + from_col_n
```

basically the user will specify the exposure and outcome so i'm not worried about that piece.

**Expected Output:**

```
tidy_ggdag <- dagify(
  A ~ D + G + Q,
  D ~ G,
  exposure = "G",
  outcome = "A"
) %>% 
  tidy_dagitty()
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this could help a bit

```
with(
  aggregate(
    . ~ to,
    unique(as.data.frame(arc.set)),
    paste0,
    collapse = "+"
  ),
  sapply(paste0(to, "~", from), as.formula)
)
```

and you will see

```
$`A~Q+G+D`
A ~ Q + G + D
<environment: 0x000000001af2b280>

$`D~G`
D ~ G
<environment: 0x000000001af2b280>
```

Comment: Thanks! but how do i put them both in a long string separated by a comma?

Comment: @Eisen Maybe you can try using `do.call(dagify, c(f, exposure = "G", outcome = "A")`, where `f` is the output of my code.